# Как можно наследовать фабрику?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть такого вида фабрика, как ее можно наследовать?

```
appServices.factory('Parent', ['$resource', '$rootScope',
    function ($resource, $rootScope) {
        var service = function () {
          this.items = [];
        }
            service.prototype.load = function (query) {}
            service.prototype.update = function (query) {}
            service.prototype.delete = function (query) {}
        return service;
    }
]);
```

Comment: а зачем наследовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сервис и фабрика это разные понятия в мире Angular. Фабрику, которая у вас в примере, как раз таки можно пронаследовать, т.к. она возвращает непосредственно саму функцию конструктор, которой достаточно для наследования. Сервис же при инициализации создаст экземпляр родителя.

```
.factory('ParentFactory', function () {
    var Parent = function () {
        this.items = [];
    }
    Parent.prototype.load = function (query) {}
    Parent.prototype.update = function (query) {}
    Parent.prototype.delete = function (query) {}
    return Parent;
})
.factory('ChildFactory', function (ParentFactory) {
    var Child = function () {
        // инициализация родителя, если необходима
        ParentFactory.call(this);
        // свои свойства
        this.limit = 10;
    }
    // наследование
    Child.prototype = Object.create(ParentFactory.prototype);
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child;

    // свои методы
    Child.prototype.insert = function (query) {}

    return Child;
})
```

[Пример на Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/s5EZXgB10zNUSn6kxebH?p=preview)

Comment: Хм... Я бы наоборот сервис наследовал, а не фабрику, т. к. тот создаётся через new. Хотя это разные вещи - тут фабрика предоставляет конструктор, а там был бы экземпляр, но тоже с наследованием.

Comment: Сори опечатался, когда писал почему то подумал про сервис, а так всё работает по примеру, прям как я и хотел

Answer (score 2):

Наследовать нельзя, можно декорировать.
[$provide.decorator(name, decorator);](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#decorator)

Comment: а можно небольшой примерчик в ответ с чилдом?

Comment: А то читаю про декоратор не понимаю как вне контроллера и конфига его применить, а потом перегрузить внутренние методы фабрики

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich, не перегрузить, а именно переписать, параметр _decorator_ это функция, первый параметр которой - это объект сервиса который декорируется, ему можно просто добавить/переписать существующее свойство, какое нужно, и вернуть из этой функции